# expanding the exponential term in the multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have the pdf for a d-dimensional Gaussian as follows:

$P_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^d|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({x}-{\mu})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({x}-{\mu})\right)$

I'd like to expand the exponential term 
$-\frac{1}{2}({x}-{\mu})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({x}-{\mu})$ 
but am not sure how the covariance matrix factors into the "foiling."

This is what I came up with, is this the correct expansion? 
$-\frac{1}{2}({x}^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}{x} -\mu{x}^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1} - \mu^Tx{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1} + \mu^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}\mu)$

can this be further simplified if it is correct? Thank you!!

Comment: Since matrix multiplication is not commutative, you must multiply the factors in each term in the same order they came. For example, since $\mu$ was on the right it has to stay on the right, not get multiplied on the left of $x^T.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed answer can’t be quite right, since, *e.g.* $x^\text{T}\Sigma^{-1}x$ is a scalar, while $\mu{x^\text{T}}\Sigma^{-1}$ is a matrix (so it doesn’t make sense to add them together).

In general, to expand $(x-c)^\text{T}A(x-c)$ for vectors $x$ and $c$ and a matrix $A$, first distribute the $A$:
$$
(x-c)^\text{T}A(x-c)=(x-c)^\text{T}(Ax-Ac). 
$$
Then you can pass the transpose through the parentheses to get $(x^\text{T}-c^\text{T})(Ax-Ac)$.
Next, apply “FOIL”. The first term is $x^\text{T}Ax$, the outer term is $-x^\text{T}Ac$, *etc*.

Comment: Why didn't you distribute the transpose into (x-c) before "foiling" the expression? Would this step be incorrect?

Comment: @kkun That’s fine—see updated answer